# cloudflare api запрос

Tags: nginx, api, cloudflare

домен привязан через cloudflare к моему ip серверу. возникла проблема когда делаешь get запрос и получаешь json с данными больше 300 строк. он не загружает, точнее просто грузит 50% данных и остается в режиме загрузки, запрос не выполняется. если напрямую делать запрос через ip:port, а не через домен/api, то все нормально работает